# Switching Cpanel site from using Domain to IP?

Tags: cpanel, web-deployment

I am switching our site from one server to another, but need to test its all working without changing the domain, how can I change it so it accepts connections to the IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have tagged Cpanel so if it is Cpanel/WHM,it includes facility of temp URL which generally goes like http://IPaddress/~cpanelusername

This should load the webcontents of your "publichtml" of Cpanel account.

Please specify the details of your controlpanel on both servers if you are not referring to Cpanel-WHM.

Comment: Thanks that was it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to check your site from new server without changing domain nameserver.

To check our domain from new server, You need to update your local PC host file ( C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts ) with new IP and your domain so that you can test your domain from new server.

Comment: I dont want to do that as I still need to access the old site, If I go to the sites IP I get a 404 page